# error while installind TP-Link "RT-WN723n" Driver

Tags: wireless, drivers

hello I am trying to install the TP-Link "RT-WN723n" driver but I get this error:

```
make: *** /lib/modules/3.8.0-27-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

please how to solve it

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 64x

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to install the appropriate kernel headers package? I think the /lib/modules build tree gets populated as part of that

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: First thank you for your answer.. I did as you told me I hace another problem you can see the output here http://justpaste.it/3art